# ARC in Swift how to resolve strong reference cycle when assign property as function

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

Flowing code, I did try to create an object assign object property to a functions. And after init object I did try assign it to nil. But object did not release (because deinit never called).

I think problem is strong reference cycle between property and owner object. If really has strong reference cycle here, how to resolve this problem when assign property directly with a function?

```
class MyClass {
    var aProperty: (() -> ())?

    init() {
        // problem when assign property as a method
        self.aProperty = aMethod
    }

    func aMethod() {
        print("method!!!")
    }

    deinit {
        print("MyClass is being deinitialized")
    }
}


var instance: MyClass? = MyClass()
instance?.aProperty?()
instance = nil
```

Comment: Apart from the given answers: you should make aProperty private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use a capture list to prevent the cycle. Just wrap the method call in a closure as shown in the code below.

```
class MyClass {
    var aProperty: (() -> ())?

    init() {
        // use a capture list to prevent a reference cycle
        self.aProperty = { [unowned self] in self.aMethod() }
    }

    func aMethod() {
        print("method!!!")
    }

    deinit {
        print("MyClass is being deinitialized")
    }
}


var instance: MyClass? = MyClass()
instance?.aProperty?()
instance = nil
```

This eliminates the strong reference cycle in my testing.

Comment: this code did set self.aProperty to a closure, not a function. And call function in closure. I want to find answer about "has anyway to assign property to function directly"?

Comment: How would assigning a method directly differ in terms of functionality? A function is just a type of closure after all.

Comment: I think I did write a confusing question, and I did edit my question. I don't think a function is just closure . Closure capture value in context and function did not

Comment: yes I did find many way to do but I think need call function via closure, not assign directly. Thank

Comment: Glad this helped. Just as a matter of terminology, the Swift documentation seems to define "closures" to include all functions whether they capture anything or not. And I wish the documentation explained the different capturing scenarios more, because it certainly is not always clear what's the compiler is doing.

Comment: All instance methods have an implicit reference to self, so that's why you need to wrap it using the closure syntax and provide a capture list when assigning it to a property. But assigning an instance method to an instance property of the same object doesn't sound very useful!

Answer (score 1):

You resolve a strong reference cycle between a closure and a class instance by defining a capture list as part of the closure’s definition. A capture list defines the rules to use when capturing one or more reference types within the closure’s body. As with strong reference cycles between two class instances, you declare each captured reference to be a weak or unowned reference rather than a strong reference. The appropriate choice of weak or unowned depends on the relationships between the different parts of your code.

```
lazy var someClosure: Void -> String = {
[unowned self, weak delegate = self.delegate!] in
// closure body goes here
```

}

from
[Strong Reference Cycles for Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID56)

In your case you should apply capture list when assigning a method to the property like this

```
init() {
    self.aProperty = { [unowned self] in self.aMethod() }
}
```

Comment: as my question we can use closure capture list to resolve this problem when we assign property to closure. But we can't use capture list in case of function